# Is it possible to strip the content from the enveloped XaDES signature to get the detached signature

Tags: xml, cryptography, digital-signature, xades

I am using [DSS](https://github.com/esig/dss) library to verify digital signature. Recently, DSS introduced the ability to send just the hash of the document being verified and it's signature without sending the actual content. That may be a good thing for privacy, because you could potentially avoid sending the document to the server (on our system the verification component runs on the backend). In order to do that we need to strip the content away from the signature, calculate hash over it and send it to the DSS to verify.

This all sounds good, but when we actually try to strip the content and send the created "detached" signature for verification along with the hash we get an exception from DSS:
`WARN  [eu.europa.esig.dss.xades.validation.XAdESSignature] (default task-7) Determining signing certificate from certificate candidates list failed: [Certificate #1: Signature verification failed, Certificate #2: Signature length not correct: got 256 but was expecting 512`

This doesn't make much sense as all of the certificate digests are 256 bit long, not 512.

Here's the actual stripped signature:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="id-448b15cfb37f10f659949fe53afb3bcc"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference Id="r-id-448b15cfb37f10f659949fe53afb3bcc-1"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116"><ds:XPath>not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)</ds:XPath></ds:Transform><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>VkPkiQYDbE3NZ2fQv7pwDInIY0YjQAbVJvulFHITSoI=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xades-id-448b15cfb37f10f659949fe53afb3bcc"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>04YiTp2wqxQpL0DlG0NvJcnnVwdacoykFMBbsfZhajU=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue Id="value-id-448b15cfb37f10f659949fe53afb3bcc">v4fKeQwUI0XYAsTJPti3GYDUCsdyCvUJV0RUXAd9vqyuij7pqaVNK/6/uSnGViokCB8w5w3/T1NPNJTXZ5ahY183Fo86j7MHf2BYjy0K+jSbflG0GGOnVPtpQ05qjVgfKRTAo/xjjKZWgBEAR2hQGSm4eF79I302i9SPDSqy6BuKMCa0d32lyzsmJRSN64ySCbAGx3qxtLjUskhQf73rZnYS8t5TLz5h6wA6hPMLTAIHp5J/LVcznuCSjcP14dll/ZqPvJI5pMp+J3dGU3XjYkylGAX8fx2gO52d1/IRJGubVPM2Sc60xV+iwk3ufS4PwOHZwu7svQwU8Ei8LZ+gCQ==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIG4jCCBMqgAwIBAgIJROVSTMAL7eJgMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlJTMRAwDgYDVQQHDAdCZW9ncmFkMQ8wDQYDVQQKDAZOZXRTZVQxGDAWBgNVBAMMD0Nsb3VkIENBIE5ldFNlVDAeFw0xOTEyMTgxMzQyMTlaFw0yMjEyMTgxMzQyMTlaMIGdMQswCQYDVQQGEwJSUzEPMA0GA1UECAwGU2VyYmlhMREwDwYDVQQHDAhCZWxncmFkZTEOMAwGA1UEEQwFMTEwNzAxGjAYBgNVBAkMEVBhcmlza2Uga29tdW5lIDI0MRIwEAYDVQQEDAlSYWRvc2V2aWMxDzANBgNVBCoMBk5pa29sYTEZMBcGA1UEAwwQTmlrb2xhIFJhZG9zZXZpYzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAM8uNqgZGbmTy1K4gjWiWLKwCKdwhipCwXJOllKCamOUvyQmykUJRrs3JjBhYkdOdQA9UyGCs/5JLgmVA6EeEEKWJGEZmKwv8JQvcp09J1Iovc7hcv+rQvsQUJqnlsrZX9eagvyO4p90xMoNdqpk9vFtW29cKB7qhw6nBUYzpbW26wa3q7tgdS9s9cF8OWfh1LGkAdVNdXnCVsBLn3wpOn2cjFZuStksMldN4dqa/N2yglBuLPd94xxUP1KR5DlIBwXSRhQtQedWbpLxz0EVwoboino6VkqTlc9kolcPxpHHQ5OQdpXXx2pjFxI6U0Kw6jkjm6DpOiyGLi6v6HowZK0CAwEAAaOCAnUwggJxMAkGA1UdEwQCMAAwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgbAMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFAPpPpldBu73UZtn3v+c6oGACeRWMB0GA1UdDgQWBBTpMNMINjCsPaBc769k7862JW3fVDBABgNVHR8EOTA3MDWgM6Axhi9odHRwOi8vc3RhcmZpc2h0ZXN0Lm5ldHNldGdsb2JhbC5ycy9jbG91ZGNhLmNybDCBnQYIKwYBBQUHAQMBAf8EgY0wgYowOgYIKwYBBQUHCwIwLgYHBACL7EkBATAjhiFodHRwOi8vY2EubmV0c2V0LnJzL2Rva3VtZW50YWNpamEwCAYGBACORgEBMAgGBgQAjkYBBDAWBgYEAI5GAQIwDBMDZXVyAgEAAgID6DALBgYEAI5GAQMCARQwEwYGBACORgEGMAkGBwQAjkYBBgEwgZgGCCsGAQUFBwEBBIGLMIGIMDsGCCsGAQUFBzAChi9odHRwOi8vc3RhcmZpc2h0ZXN0Lm5ldHNldGdsb2JhbC5ycy9jbG91ZGNhLmNydDBJBggrBgEFBQcwAYY9aHR0cDovL3Brc2NhLm5ldHNldGdsb2JhbC5yczo4MDgwL29jc3AvcmVzcG9uZGVyL3Brc2Nsb3Vkb2NzcDCBlgYDVR0gBIGOMIGLMCcGBgQAizABATAdMBsGCCsGAQUFBwIBFg9odHRwOi8vZXRzaS5jb20wJwYGBACLMAECMB0wGwYIKwYBBQUHAgEWD2h0dHA6Ly9ldHNpLmNvbTALBgcEAIvsQAECMAAwKgYJKoF6AWkKBAEDMB0wGwYIKwYBBQUHAgEWD2h0dHA6Ly9uZWtpLmNvbTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAJp8rru1bx3LDYG2lfruitO9qcV2CwgGNWXPt10zAi/nyZjY/HvMonjQGC86bUkYyEMw21cjYfHdCs8BLUid5I5Hbj2htGYZvRXx+R6ci0nlhmzXXv1acws9Zn9E8gfk4zosI8tHrJhPnJZuPWcDjS1QDJG6U74kbQpN2JnfM2VFvXiyjb0t4J/ZxskY3hb+IBEVPL8Kn3oQRTPYC0kEECq2UPZkRmKOFimWs8bRoqbAG3IWf+qRlENFiU+cjhdV1NYAiiMnd64EU6+zbxOJn0X4YjJz01xgLeaS4uridA9alAR5gHxL8LBMvM+i4cgkqTf9hguC0VTaiPfsrfu7/s0VA4wbE0ebk1ZUIb3bs9eLhq3E6h6V4Wuqe6lGNORuJgok/K64DoU7RPL/yVJRxPBt55tvNxQBZ+d+StAAMWXxJmw5lTn3vs0jdzzXLP1HrtNk0sDldzXlSoqwcGrXcyCcbIfVCdsDaOpGlTc9o2bMMJ06WjEZ9Wz8YhTWYftiJhES8h3m0BYicVJYGgYY5huvM1CZq495M68C/FffZG/tBcI34epWm2kb7lRt7mq/+5Ts4519YL5uFHqYWhfHmABQmT8i/yzFpdlP6aMmXyssDP9TK/f/f2fttalICfMZoDBQY15At2xEkXMAG3yMyI0dA19RXn1ZzMwjZfZII4YA=</ds:X509Certificate><ds:X509Certificate>MIIGbTCCBFWgAwIBAgIJF2ZKhDYQKGe2MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEkxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlJTMRAwDgYDVQQHDAdCZW9ncmFkMQ8wDQYDVQQKDAZOZXRTZVQxFzAVBgNVBAMMDlJvb3QgQ0EgTmV0U2VUMB4XDTE5MTIxNzA4NDI0NVoXDTQ0MTIxNjE3MzA0NVowSjELMAkGA1UEBhMCUlMxEDAOBgNVBAcMB0Jlb2dyYWQxDzANBgNVBAoMBk5ldFNlVDEYMBYGA1UEAwwPQ2xvdWQgQ0EgTmV0U2VUMIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAtHsLnZdvGEV3Ga9qFHiA4AbsHNRyuswxpYMn6yqn4WLg4RMSiwoL7RlQqK4L/5YvEykovUNKfgyIfBfmEPJD69oEGfpLL7pL2mQ3ls99l6fo4LCCizg8hQ6V2HIQ3uNn9kUg/7wJNyBliomfn5iOt6CNi8oGFeG25PoFjQwfALeywJsFCZqhk67E6Ym65NWb/J0ETigZJ/u4jp0jz5Z2x1sniQzwTeB6OLDRKfod4f0QzDYHV3OK3JvZZ3v+qBKqhhFynPOhFM1iM+2cTHBaEOXG8D9xF7/rBJiMPZahk+GFBt3ESBnbfQg7wM2tgzW64KekSypWxAS7Q8h2c+mrnsMh80HLrRcXatd9tmOiC2dswzjGs25YqhPx5hrVlu0XbZ0rC902w8q6siQQYH1i+XyDSYd++r2vFtzknvSmfHeAsbswuSUL21+9rYTVbUO+NITKblvew2ZqIwq1/sRrBWvu3IsuQ7thBvaC1QJtM5PXP2UvKoPbFdOtSlvpt98NBNigvLurwveRxy7ObTkRk2qcPqmdS39vEB0Vq0UDL2k/vvGnjZC0jeI+87cBSMGDPlY7zJJZZ37RX4ad/xEUkr2YYiEIKr2sHQzh0sVoOiXk2yfISagY2P4cwBIHNFZTMFdJh4xtCdsOPwS9rkRARqgpTGQOr/81EUufcaHodHUCAwEAAaOCAVUwggFRMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQAwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFOJl5dmktrA3AM0gptZbcUDxvk5bMB0GA1UdDgQWBBQD6T6ZXQbu91GbZ97/nOqBgAnkVjA/BgNVHR8EODA2MDSgMqAwhi5odHRwOi8vc3RhcmZpc2h0ZXN0Lm5ldHNldGdsb2JhbC5ycy9yb290Y2EuY3JsMEoGCCsGAQUFBwEBBD4wPDA6BggrBgEFBQcwAoYuaHR0cDovL3N0YXJmaXNodGVzdC5uZXRzZXRnbG9iYWwucnMvcm9vdGNhLmNydDBeBgNVHSAEVzBVMFMGBFUdIAAwSzAuBggrBgEFBQcCARYiaHR0cDovL25ldHNldC5ycy9kb2t1bWVudGFjaWphLnBkZjAZBggrBgEFBQcCAjANDAtOZXRTZXQgZG9jczANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAGsToOTQswJ7CPbtvTjJbbi9JTVAv1r2nCV5GmfS0d0ZPsQiY7/egnUDFH8njrWfwjKl2KVXOibnWB2VRYY1mW2VTK0JsIQGrrQ9SihmqnBjZn3Hb2MkpnLtQthCGevJsOlnp7ZlWd6tJCnXYj9JFLaz8uIt1ILUA9Uq2brphLAgkSN1RICzOPqUISozPgEXepoBNap05lBTyyGoBKqm+tXc9iOZwVgI+IDoAbpMICAXuPXtXyFNyFxRb5Rw8llg+mBoPEKPzH/qRTqUxyqOWC68CM2qczycUOQVyF4med9fYa0a/AjVKu3uhhXhDSiCRi06x1LdTlHwHRXpoLWn4k4xcJdgLwM0k/CtBu+TsuMy+zatodVcGyfnfRi/jJm8cHGy8QFWH2yLiENhHwZIQv+HL2lr1mUpmUVJ6gZrie9Cd6DWcUKfIAVWXjhfDLmTm4ZHD7jn5LoJplFe2RKSzbia7/YA/w3sV1B87uFXD4ZnQGibW1rl+obn7xQlkJGRJxsWAKZiE50FlaskH3ETzSLFxtYH/0jv9liukLnyJh27jxSEqXdEEatWlVH/XYogbMEW4CbxJIxfXPp69l4gCirQooheNuXJGbBa1lQAmcPCJFUUW8MwX9jUldf6NMUsX/uGqYQxeKnDHyfj5iAsdyZpQ2bqfTbRp97wsYa+Qrk0=</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo><ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="#id-448b15cfb37f10f659949fe53afb3bcc"><xades:SignedProperties Id="xades-id-448b15cfb37f10f659949fe53afb3bcc"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2020-07-19T12:46:29Z</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificateV2><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512"/><ds:DigestValue>3oKjV/svZGkzE8RfAtPDgk7+CFifLKrTwDKlAJKlUr1uKyC4HP6IkOdkOjWb8/QY8W8E1TPl0FKFadiMof0mpQ==</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerialV2>MFswTqRMMEoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlJTMRAwDgYDVQQHDAdCZW9ncmFkMQ8wDQYDVQQKDAZOZXRTZVQxGDAWBgNVBAMMD0Nsb3VkIENBIE5ldFNlVAIJROVSTMAL7eJg</xades:IssuerSerialV2></xades:Cert></xades:SigningCertificateV2></xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SignedDataObjectProperties><xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#r-id-448b15cfb37f10f659949fe53afb3bcc-1"><xades:MimeType>application/octet-stream</xades:MimeType></xades:DataObjectFormat></xades:SignedDataObjectProperties></xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object></ds:Signature>
```

**EDIT:** Since the problem seems to be about the actual signature and the digest value used as the input, like dave_thompson_085 has pointed out, I tried to get the digest from the SignatureValue manually to try to figure out what's going on.

So, I took the certificate #1 value and run the following command to extract the public key:

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem > pubkey.pem
```

Then I took the value from the SignatureValue tag and run the following command to decrypt the signature and get the digest:

```
openssl rsautl -inkey pubkey.pem -pubin -in sig.bin -out result.bin
```

However, when I base64 encoded the result using some online tool to compare it to the digest that I was passing and that was included in the actual signature, I got the following `'MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEIDBaM9z9ZgShg0Ev6X38gyfjQXHlWsyRTbJ3RBUvMeNB'`. This is weird because it's longer that the actual 32-byte digest that I expected and doesn't resemble anything I expected (when I check the binary version of the file I got it's actually 64-byte long). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's talking about the length of the signature (in bytes), not the digest (in bits). It's true your certificate#2, which is a CA cert, has a 4096-bit=512-byte RSA key and its signatures would be 512 bytes -- but it shouldn't even be a candidate because it doesn't match the SigningCertificateV2 element. Your SignatureValue is 256 bytes which does match the keysize in certificate#1, and does modexp-and-PKCS1-unpad under that key, but apparently the verifier thinks the resulting hash doesn't match your data, and that part I can't easily check, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually calculated digest from the content and got the value of 'VkPkiQYDbE3NZ2fQv7pwDInIY0YjQAbVJvulFHITSoI=' which is actually the value present in the signature itself under the '<ds:DigestValue>' tag. The DSS library actually hash a method that accepts hash algorithm, hash and signature. I passed the SHA-256, the hash I calculated which matches the one in the DigestValue tag and the detached signature I posted (that I got when stripping it away from the enveloped signature).  What I get as a response from DSS is "subIndication":"SIG_CRYPTO_FAILURE",

Comment: `openssl rsautl -verify` un-does (and `-sign` does) only half the PKCS1 padding; specifically it does NOT do step 2, ASN.1 DigestInfo, of [EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#section-9.2). However, while the hash of the actual data is put in the DigestValue in Reference in SignedInfo, that is not what the RSA signature is computed over and thus not the hash extracted from rsautl; see https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-CoreGeneration . You need to canonicalize the SignedInfo, and I don't have a separable tool for that.

Comment: FYI `rsautl -verify/-encrypt` can use the cert directly with `-certin`, so you don't need to separately extract the pubkey.